# plaster boarding an existing ceiling and locating pipes and electrics

Tags: ceiling

Hi I have located the joist with no problems. I now need advice on how to avoid putting my drywall screws into pipework or electric cable as I screw through the plasterboard.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Find the joist at each end and snap a chalk line so you know where to put your screws. The national electric code requires wires to be 1-1/4 away from the edges so you should be fine putting screws in along the line. If you hit a spot the screw wont go in there may be a metal plate protecting the wires that are two close and sheetrock screws will not punch through the plates if there or metal pipe.